# Getting "new" dependency from org.eclipse.xtext.common.types

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, xtext

I'm looking for a confirmation that version 2.9.1 of org.eclipse.xtext.common.types always had the following org.eclipse.core.runtime dependency tree:

[image]

Since ~2 weeks, our build are getting an additional JAR (org.eclipse.core.runtime, version 3.14.0). So far we can't explain why ... and are looking if ever possible that anything on Xtext version 2.9.1 recently changes? We doubt, but who knows?

The dependency has been set as Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.xtext</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtext.common.types</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

==============================================

Additional information based on my findings ... This is the pom.xml of org.eclipse.xtext.common.types Artifact (version 2.9.1):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.xtext</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtext.tycho.parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    <relativePath>../../maven/org.eclipse.xtext.tycho.parent</relativePath>
</parent>
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

<name>Common Types Runtime Library</name>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.xtext.common.types</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.xtext</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtext.util</artifactId>
        <version>[${project.version}]</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.xtext</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtext</artifactId>
        <version>[${project.version}]</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.codegen</artifactId>
        <version>${emf.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>${google-inject.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
        <version>${asm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore</artifactId>
        <version>${emf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.common</artifactId>
        <version>${emf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.lib</artifactId>
        <version>${mwe2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

${emf.version} is a range from (2.8:3.0) ... Looking at following: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.emf/org.eclipse.emf.codegen

... Version 2.14 is actually very recent (Sept. 2018).

Xtext guys, do you confirm that before version 2.14, no dependency to eclipse core runtime version 3.14.0 was set?

Comment: Are you using it as OSGi dependency bundle or as usual Maven/POM dependency? Furthermore have you defined the deps with version ranges?

Comment: I'm using it as Maven dependency, without any version range, but rather with a fix version:  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.xtext</groupId>
   <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtext.common.types</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, I added the information on the main description.

Comment: it has a range thus a newer core.runtime version will be pulled as soon as it is published at eclipse. this is fixed in xtext 2.15. emf 2.15 might even pull a newer one (will be fixed in xtext 2.16)

Comment: => you are affected by publishment of newer emf artifacts

Comment: org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.codegen was published on sept. 14th

Comment: Thanks Christian, this confirms what I found/thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EMF 2.15 and thus 
org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.codegen:2.14.0 where published on September 14th. the newer emf version has these new dependencies. All Xtext versions < 2.15 automatically pull the new emf version. if you want to avoid that you can switch back to emf 2.12 / codegen 2.11 should solve that issues (https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/blob/v2.15.0/gradle/versions.gradle)